# Using R, how to filter a column to keep item contained in another?

Tags: r

I do have a dataframe like this one

```
columna <- c(1,2,3)
columnb <- c("a b e", "c d", "a c d")
columnc <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
alldata <- data.frame(columna,columnb,columnc)
tokeep <- c("c", "e")
```

And i would like to get the same `alldata` with `columnb` modified to only keep in `columnb` the strings found in `tokeep`.

Ideally, i would like to have `alldata$columnb` to be

```
[ "e", "c", "c" ]
```

I first thought i could use something like

```
filter(alldata, alldata$columnb %in% tokeep)
alldata[which(alldata$b %in% tokeep), ]
```

but i can't manage to find a solution.

Can someone guide me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `gsub` to substitute the characters which we dont want with an empty string

```
alldata$columnb<- gsub(paste0("[^",paste0(tokeep,collapse = "|"),"]"),"", alldata$columnb)

alldata
#  columna columnb    columnc
#1       1       e 2010-11-01
#2       2       c 2008-03-25
#3       3       c 2007-03-14
```

The regular expression which we are creating is

```
paste0("[^",paste0(tokeep, collapse = "|"), "]")

#[1] "[^c|e]"
```

which means anything except `c` or `e`.

**EDIT**

As per Wiktor's comment we probably need regex as

```
paste0("[^",paste0(tokeep,collapse = ""),"]")
#[1] "[^ce]"
```

Comment: I regret i can't vote at the moment. This is so clever Ronak !

Comment: `[^c|e]` means not `c`, `|` and `e`, you definitely do not need a `|`. Also, `[^e]` is a negated *character* class, it won't work with strings of more than 1 char.

Comment: I see. Thank you Wiktor. As per the example shown by OP I am assuming values in `columnb` are of 1 char only.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
alldata$columnb <- str_extract(alldata$columnb, paste(tokeep, collapse="|"))
alldata$columnb
[#1] "e" "c" "c"
```