# Using R, how to use str_extract properly on this case?

Tags: r, regex

I've learned from Ronak Shah and akrun([in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816293/using-r-how-to-filter-a-column-to-keep-item-contained-in-another/40817144#40817144)) how to construct a regular expression to exclude every terms from a dataframe (alldata in my example) except those words,

> ^\BWORD1|WORD2|WORD3|WORD4|WORD5\>

but for some reasons, can't figure why it is giving me

> "WORD2", "WORD3", NA

instead of

> "WORD1 WORD2 WORD5", "WORD3", NA

here is my example :

```
library(stringr)
alldata <- data.frame(toupper(c("word1 anotherword word2 word5", "word3", "none")))
names(alldata)<-"columna"
removeex <- c("word1" , "word2"  ,"word3" ,"word4", "word5")
regularexprex <- toupper(paste0("^\\b",paste0(removeex, collapse = "|"), "\\>"))
alldata$columnb <- str_extract(alldata$columna, regularexprex)
```

I've tried to add + or * at the end of the regular expression but without any effects.

Due to the fact i'm a beginner on regex, i surely miss something, may someone guide me on this  ?
Regards,

Comment: You mean you need to get NA for all entries that are  in a specific list?

Comment: I want to keep all the words inside the dataframe that are present in the list, delete the rest. If not present, i'll get a NA. Sorry for being not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the last two lines in your above code to

```
> regularexprex <- paste0("(?i)\\s*\\b(?!(?:",paste0(removeex, collapse = "|"), ")\\b)\\w+")
## => "(?i)\\s*\\b(?!(?:word1|word2|word3|word4|word5)\\b)\\w+"
> str_replace_all(alldata$columna, regularexprex, "")
[1] "WORD1 WORD2 WORD5" "WORD3"             ""
```

First, the `toupper()` turned `\b` to `\B` (non-word boundary) - you just need a case insensitive matching (I added the `(?i)` modifier), and the word boundaries were not applied to the group, only to the items on the both sides.

Also, what you need is a pattern to match the whole string, so `.*` at the start and end of the pattern.

The final regex for *replacing* looks like

```
(?i)\s*\b(?!(?:word1|word2|word3|word4|word5)\b)\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YWamFD/1)

If your entries contain newlines, you should also add `s` modifier: `(?i)` -> `(?s)`.

**Details**:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier (works with PCRE and ICU regexes)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\b`  -  a leading word boundary
- `(?!(?:word1|word2|word3|word4|word5)\b)` - the word cannot equal `word1`, etc.
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters, digits or underscores).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, but ANOTHERWORD is still in the list as it don't belong to the list word1|word2|word3|word4|word5. How may i exclude it ?
Thanks for your help and link.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, 
if i am using (?i).*\b(word1|word2|word3|word4|word5)\b.* ,i'm getting word5  and word3 on 2nd line.  
I don't understand how to have word1 word2 word5 on 1st line and word5 on 2nd line.

Comment: See the updated answer. You seem to want to remove any word that is not in the list.